# Graph Isomorphisms for G and its Complement

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph and G' be its complement.

A) Show that the number of graph isomorphisms from G to itself is equal to the number of graph isomorphisms from G' to itself.

B) Let A be the adjacency matrix for G. Derive a formula for the adjacency matrix of G' using constant matrices and A.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A) Show that every graph isomorphism $G \rightarrow G$ defines a graph isomorphism $G' \rightarrow G'$ using the same vertex mapping.

B) What do you get if you add the adjacency matrix of $G$ to the adjacency matrix of $G'$?

Comment: For A, I don't really understand how to do that. For B, that would give you the adjacency matrix for the complete graph, right?

Comment: When are two vertices adjacent in $G'$? And yes, it would give you the adjacency matrix of the complete graph.

Comment: Two vertices are adjacent in G' if they are not adjacent in G. And I've got B now. Thanks!